# FreeBSD + Apache24 + php55-5.5.10 + Ports

Tags: php, freebsd, ports

Also I need some help...
My Ports are updated on my FreeBSD 9.0. I already have the Apache24 installed (IMG.1), but when trying to install php55-5.5.10 (IMG.2) don't have Build Apache Module option.

Is anyone else experiencing this?

[Apache24 (IMG.1)](http://forums.freebsd.org/download/file.php?id=2100)
[PHP55-5.5.10 (IMG.2)](http://forums.freebsd.org/download/file.php?id=2101)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Apache PHP module is separated of port PHP principal. For fix it, install the port "**/usr/ports/www/mod_php5**" or "**/usr/ports/www/mod_php55**", according to the version of PHP installed.

Answer (score 3):

The `APACHE` option existed in lang/php55 version 5.5.9, but has been dropped from 5.5.10.  The idea was that Apache modules should live together in the "www" category, so mod_php got its own port.

When trying to figure this sort of thing out, always check **`/usr/ports/UPDATING`** for notes on changes.  In this case, there's an entry from a week ago:

```
20140327:
  AFFECTS: users of lang/php5 and lang/php55 with Apache module
  AUTHOR: ale@FreeBSD.org

  The Apache PHP module has been separated from the main PHP port.
  If it is needed, install either www/mod_php5 or www/mod_php55.
```

Answer (score 0):

Install the mod_php port/package.